# Can ImageMagick use specific number formats as in 'printf()' in the option '-format'?

Tags: imagemagick

I am using 'ImageMagick' command `identify` to calculate the area of images in pixels:

```
$ identify -format "%[fx:w*h]\n"  example-small.jpg 
699392

$ identify -format "%[fx:w*h]\n"  example-large.jpg
1.80497e+07
```

In the second case, the output is in the scientific format: `1.80497e+07`.
This is the case if the area is larger than some threshold (>= 1000000).

The option can be used with the 'ImageMagick' commands `convert`, `identify` and `mogrify`.

**Is it possible to make the `%[fx: ... ]' format option use a specific number format in itself?**

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to make the `%[fx: ... ]' format option use a specific number format in itself?

Yes and No. When parsing `%[fx: ... ]` format, ImageMagick stores the result as `double` data type. This value will be passed to stdlib `vsnprintf()` method with a `%.*g` format. The output would result in the scientific notation for "extreme" numbers.

For the "yes" part. Since you're working with two unsigned integers (`w*h`), you may be able to spoof the behavior of `vnsprintf()` by setting the precision operator in ImageMagick.

```
identify -precision 32 -format "%[fx:w*h]\n"  example-large.jpg
```

However this is not a true "*fix*". It may not always work between systems, and adjusting the overall precision might have unforeseen side effects.

For the "no" part. It might be more practical & reliable to use an external utility  to format the results to a format you can control.

```
printf "%.f" $(identify -format "%[fx:w*h]" example-large.jpg)
```

True that it is inconvenient, but a quick search for "[[bash] scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D%20scientific%20notation)" offers many alternative ways as this a common task.